# How do I insert some columns of a table into a new record with the same value of other columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a stage table with the following sample values. I want to create a new record if there are more than one name or city along with other columns. How can I do this?

Sample values:

```
id  pr  name1   city1   name2   city2   name3   city3   state   country
c1  p1  name11  city11  name21  city21  name31  city31  s1      country1
c2  p2  name12  city12  NULL    city22  NULL    NULL    s2      country2
c3  p3  name13  city13  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    s3      country3
c4  p4  name14  city14  name24  city24  name34  NULL    s4      country4
c5  p4  name15  city15  name25  city25  NULL    NULL    s5      country5
```

Expected output:

```
id  pr  name    city    state   country
c1  p1  name11  city11  s1      country1
c1  p1  name21  city21  s1      country1
c1  p1  name31  city31  s1      country1
c2  p2  name12  city12  s2      country2
c2  p2  NULL    city22  s2      country2
c3  p3  name13  city13  s3      country3
```

I tried to unpivot the columns. But it didn't work.

Comment: Tables don't have "records" they have columns and rows. Hopefully, the reason you're asking this question is to fix your design, as it's denormalised. Also, I do suggest lookign at upgrade paths; SQL Server 2008 is completely unsupported and has been since July last year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `apply` to unpivot the data:

```
select t.id, t.pr, v.name, v.city, t.state, t.country
from t cross apply
     (values (t.name1, t.city1), (t.name2, t.city2), (t.name3, t.city3)
     ) v(name, city)
where v.name is not null;
```

Comment: @Madhukar. . . It is `t`.